# Renaming folders based on their name prefix

Tags: python

For example here is my list of folders:

```
foldername_java, foldername_new , foldername_old, myprogram_1, mylist_2, mylist_21, mylist_22
```

I want to rename these folders based on their's name prefix. The folders starting with 'foldername' should be renamed to include index 0, the ones starting with 'myprogram' should be renamed with index 1, and the ones starting with 'mylist' with the index 2.

The second index should increase for all next occurances of the prefix, for example:

```
mylist_2
mylist_21
mylist_22
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Almost everything is possible in almost any programming language, so yes it is possible :-). But you just forgot to say what means *the starting of folder matches*. Does it mean they have same first n letters (and what is n) ? or the starting is all what is before first (or last) `'_'` ?

Comment: i have different folder in this format. foldername_new, so the folders starting with the name as foldername   must display as 0 and the folder next to the foldername_new  must display as 1. and it goes on incrementing the numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you are asking. But the best I could make of it is that you want to rename the existing folders based on their prefix, dropping all suffixes and replacing them with integers by order of appearance, and by the prefix values. If that is the case, this can be easily done as:

```
indexes = {
    'foldername': 0,
    'myprogram': 1,
    'mylist': 2
}

folders = ['foldername_java',
           'foldername_new',
           'foldername_old',
           'myprogram_something',
           'mylist_new',
           'mylist_whatever',
           'mylist_stuff']

renamed_folders = []
for folder in folders:
    for s in indexes:
        if folder.startswith(s):
            new_folder = '{}_{}'.format(s, indexes[s])
            previous = len(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(s), renamed_folders))
            if previous:
                new_folder += str(previous)
            renamed_folders.append(new_folder)
            continue

>>> print renamed_folders
['foldername_0', 'foldername_01', 'foldername_02', 'myprogram_1', 'mylist_2', 'mylist_21', 'mylist_22']
```

Comment: Here is my list so for folder names with the name startingas acantharia 
acanthria_protist
acanthria_protist_big
acanthria_protist_halo
we need to label as 0, 
for amphipods (only single folder) we need to label as 1,
 for the folders containing withthe name starting as appendicularian
appendicularian_s_shape
appendicularian_slight_curve

 we need to label as 2 and so on.

how can i achieve this in python

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, however you are not explaining what you want to do exactly.  Maybe this will help:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

folder_list = ['foldername_java', 'foldername_new', 'foldername_old', 'myprogram_1', 'mylist_2', 'mylist_21', 'mylist_22']

indexes_list = []
arranged_list = []
final_list = []

for i in folder_list:
    prefix, suffix = i.split('_')
    if prefix in indexes_list:
        arranged_list[indexes_list.index(prefix)].append(prefix)
    else:
        indexes_list.append(prefix)
        arranged_list.append([])
        arranged_list[len(arranged_list)-1].append(prefix)

for i in arranged_list:
    c=0
    for x in i:
        c+=1
        final_list.append(x + "_" + str(c))

print(final_list)


>>> ['foldername_1', 'foldername_2', 'foldername_3', 'myprogram_1', 'mylist_1', 'mylist_2', 'mylist_3']
```

Comment: but i am nearly having 100 folders with different names. so if the starting of the folder name matches i need to label as 0.    for example 
Here is my list so for folder names with the name starting as acantharia 
acanthria_protist,
acanthria_protist_big,
acanthria_protist_halo,
we need to label as 0, 
for amphipods (only single folder) we need to label as 1,
 for the folders containing withthe name starting as appendicularian
appendicularian_s_shape,
appendicularian_slight_curve,

 we need to label as 2 and so on.

how can i achieve this in python